# generate scripts in sql server be generated as a StoredProcedure or written to a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am aware of SQL server being able to generate scripts about metadata of tables in a database. I was wondering if there is a way to do this without using the wizard. Whether it can be done using a Stored Procedure to write to a txt file or using SSIS to generate the DDL commands. I just want something so I can a job automatically overnight, so there no manual intervention running the wizard. if there is a way of doing this on SQL server Management studios using commands or SSIS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could setup a database trigger that keeps record of any change in your development database.
An example is this :

```
create TRIGGER trDDLHistory ON DATABASE
for CREATE_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION, DROP_FUNCTION,
    CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,
    CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE,
    CREATE_TRIGGER, ALTER_TRIGGER, DROP_TRIGGER,
    CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW
    -- there are more offcourse..
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblDDLHistory(DDLHistory)
    VALUES(convert(nvarchar(max), EVENTDATA()))
END;
```

example of tblDDLHistory is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDDLHistory] ( 
  [DDLHistoryID]  INT      IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
  [DDLDate]       DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
  [DDLHistory]    XML      NULL,
  CONSTRAINT   [PK_DDLHistoryID] PRIMARY KEY (DDLHistoryID)
)
```

Now you can get all changes from here to use in your production database.